# How can you make HTML Text Box print the value of console.log?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript

**How can I enter input data value in HTML Text Box?**

[image]

The output is good in `console.log`, but the HTML Text Box displays the error `Object Promise`.

[image]

I want to know how to print the value of `web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(blocknumber).input` into the Html Text box. Please help me.

These are the source code I have tried many times, but failed.

```
var transaction = web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(1865, 0).then(function (tx) {
        console.log(tx.input)
    });

tto_count.value = transaction;
```

```
web3.eth.getCoinbase(
    function (a, coinbase) {
    a = (async() => {
        await web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(1688, 0, console.log)
    })()
    document.getElementById("transaction").append("transaction input data  : " + web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(1688, 0) + "\n");
    cb = coinbase;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises are asynchronous so the flow of the code may not be in the same sequence as the lines of code.

```
var transaction = web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(1865, 0).then(function (tx) {
        console.log(tx.input)   // This executes later
    });

tto_count.value = transaction;    //This executes first
```

The result of `web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock` is available in the then block. The variable transaction will just hold the Promise returned.

Using async & await you can make it seem sequential in way.

```
web3.eth.getCoinbase(async function(a, coinbase) {
    a = await web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(4461, 0);

    document.getElementById("transaction").append("transaction input data  : " + a.input + "\n");
    cb = coinbase;        
});
```

This code will run in the same sequence as it is written. This will update your HTML as you intended to. If you're new to Javascript Promises and async-await, I would highly recommended reading about it first.